# My code outputs several "Array"

Tags: php, mysql

I just tried to create a spinner using MySQL and PHP, but after a few a hours it displays "ArrayArrayArray" in front of the expected output.

```
if($_POST['artikel']){
    $artikel = nl2br($_POST['artikel']);
    $ar = explode("\n\r",$artikel);
    $hasil = "";
    foreach($ar as $ars){
        $newstring1 = explode(" ", $ars);
        foreach($newstring1 as $newstring2){
            $newstring3 = explode("\n", $newstring2);
            foreach($newstring3 as $newstring4){
                $newstring5 = explode(",", $newstring4);
                foreach($newstring5 as $value){
                    $cari = mysql_query("select * from sinonim where kata1='$value'");
                    $j = mysql_num_rows($cari);
                    if($j>0){
                        $ka = mysql_fetch_array($cari);
                        $hasil = $hasil."<span class='re'>".$ka['kata2']." ";
                        $hasil = explode(",", $hasil);
                        foreach($hasil as $vv) {
                            $hasil = $hasil.$vv."</span> "; 
                        }
                    }else{
                        $cari2 = mysql_query("select * from sinonim where kata2='$value'");
                        $j2 = mysql_num_rows($cari2);
                        if($j2>0){
                            $ka2 = mysql_fetch_array($cari2);
                            $hasil = $hasil."<span class='re'>".stripslashes($ka2['kata1'])."</span> ";
                        }else{
                            $hasil = $hasil.$value." ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $hasil;
}
```

The result looks like this

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayhello all......
```

Why is "Array" printed? How can I avoid that?

Comment: i just think my problem here
      $hasil = explode(",", $hasil);
        foreach($hasil as $vv) {
            $hasil = $hasil.$vv."</span> "; 
       }
but i don't know where to fix

I just want result like this
hello all......
not
ArrayArrayArrayhello all......

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do? What's the input, what should be the output... It's actually nothing more than a code-soup.

Comment: The lack of indentation hurts my eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a mess. The problem occurs in this part

```
    $hasil = $hasil."<span class='re'>".$ka['kata2']." "; // line 1
    $hasil = explode(",", $hasil);                        // line 2
    foreach($hasil as $vv) {                              // line 3
        $hasil = $hasil.$vv."</span> ";                   // line 4
    }                                                     // line 5
```

In line 2 you use `explode` to split `$hasil` into an array, then in line 4 you try to append it to itself, although it's an array now not a string. This causes the "Array" output.

Eventually you want to use another variable here. Also you're adding multiple `</span>`, which will invalidate your HTML. I guess it should look like this:

```
    $hasil = $hasil."<span class='re'>".$ka['kata2']." ";
    $temp = explode(",", $hasil);
    foreach($temp as $vv) {
        $hasil = $hasil.$vv;
    }
    $hasil = $hasil."</span> ";
```

But line 4 still doesn't make sense. You're iterating over text tokens, which are already part of the output. What do you want to append here?

[In your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26005046/2) you stated that changing line 4 to `$hasil = $vv."</span> ";` solved your problem, but it looks like you're still producing invalid HTML and your code is way too complicated for what you're trying to achieve.